# Windows Phone: this version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, unity-game-engine

I'm exporting a Visual Studio Project file from Unity 4.6 for Windows Phone platform. However, `.sln` file that created by Unity cannot be open from Visual Studio 2012.

I'm getting following error.

> Unsupported This version of Visual Studio does not have the following
>   project types installed or does not support them. You can still open
>   these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were
>   originally created.
>      - xyz, "D:\data\may5\June22nd2ndBuild\xxx\xxx.csproj" No changes required These projects can be opened in this version of Visual Studio
>   without changing them. They will continue to open in Visual Studio
>   2010 SP1 and in this version of Visual Studio.
>      - xyz, "D:\data\may5\June22nd2ndBuild\xxx.sln

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **Windows Phone SDK**
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk

While not mandatory, it will also prove useful to have **Visual Studio Tools for Unity** installed
http://unityvs.com